# How to dynamically set a getter for an Objective-C object property?

Tags: objective-c, properties, getter, objective-c-runtime

`FooClass` has a property called `foo`.

It's declared as `@property (nullable, nonatomic, readonly, strong) id foo` and it has NO underlying storage, it's not synthesized. It's just a getter that by default returns `nil`.

I would like to change the implementation of this getter. I would like to create a new block/function and inject it into an object so that it replaces the original implementation.

IMPORTANT: subclassing is NOT an option. I need to take the object as is.

ALSO: I need to do it for only one, single instance, not the whole class!

How can I do it?

Comment: Can you provide some details about why you need to change the implementation of the readonly property for only a single instance of the class? Knowing what you are really trying to do can help you get better answers.

Comment: @HangarRash `WKContentView` is a private `UIView` subclass that has a getter `inputAccessoryView`. This getter is only implemented in the superclass `UIResponder`. I need, however, to change this implementation, but not for the entire `WKContentView` class, but merely for a single instance of it. I can not subclass this class directly since it's not exported from UIKit.

Comment: Did you try using `setValue(_:forKey:)`? I don't know if that will work in this case but it's easy to try. And please update your question with the details you put in that comment. It makes the information easier to find in your question.

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic response why not using the delegate pattern ?

- Add a delegate object for your class

#### Override Property getter

```objectivec
- (id)foo {
  if (delegate) { 
    [self performSelector:@Selector(someMethod) withObject:nil];
  }
  return nil;
}
```

When you want to change the method purpose set the delegate and provide your custom method impl...

#### Hardcore (not rec)

You can achieve this by using method swizzling in Objective-C. Swizzling involves swapping the implementation of methods at runtime

Comment: As I said, subclassing is not an option, and because of it, overriding a property getter via the means of the language is not an option. And swizzling here is the only solution it seems.